# File.WriteAllText() is trying to write to wrong directory

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.file

I have the following Code

```
string filePath = @"C:\temp\Test.txt";
File.WriteAllText(filePath, csvContent);
```

However when I run the console app it throws the following error...

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Code\ScheduledTextMigration\ScheduledTextMigration\bin\Debug\C\temp\Test.txt'.

Why on earth is it trying to write to that directory?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the File.WriteAllText call, run your app in the debugger. What is the value of filePath when you get to the breakpoint?

Comment: No repro here. Can you produce a [mcve] please?

Comment: The filepath is "C\\temp\\ScheduleTextMigration.txt" at the breakpoint

Comment: The `:` is missing

Comment: Well, that's different to the `filePath` you've shown us in the question and missing a `:`.

Comment: Sorry, that was me typing it. The colon is there.

Answer (score 2):

Double check your string for where

```
string filePath = @"C:\temp\Test.txt"
```

I'd be willing to bet you've missed the colon between C and \ e.g.

```
string filePath = @"C\temp\Test.txt"
```

By default the debug directory is the current path of the application (Environment.CurrentDirectory) which is used as the base of the path if you don't specify a valid path.

Comment: I copied and pasted it directly from my code. The colon is definitely there.

Comment: Whilst I was writing my answer a few comments came in, it looks like your own comment has confirmed my suggestion. "The filepath is "C\\temp\\ScheduleTextMigration.txt" at the breakpoint"

Answer (score 0):

Strange...

I moved the code to a new method (cut and pasted it) and it now works...